# Unresolved public classes in a Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to build a framework to export a few classes as an importable "package of sort".

My Framework project is called "MyFramework"... is was created as a Cocoa Touch Framework project in Swift.

I've added a single swift file called ImplementationTest.swift

It contains the following :

```
public class ImplementationTest {

    public init(){
        print("Init called");

    }

    public func echo(request: String){
        print ("Echo called with "+request);
    }


}
```

The framework builds fine and I get a MyFramework.framework folder.
I add that framework to a new swift application project and added it as Linked Framework and Library as well as Embedded Binaries.

I can "import MyFramework" just fine.
But if I try "var test=ImplementationTest()", I get the following error :
    use of unresolved identifier "ImplementationTest"

If I try "var test=MyFramework.ImplementationTest()" I get :
    module 'MyFramework' has no member name "ImplementationTest"

Am I doing this wrong ? Can my framework only have one single exported class ? and should it be named the same name as the framework itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Check after you build the framework if you can access it via in, show finder. 
If not, then try building it using generic ios device.

Comment: I did. The framework is build and it is build as "Generic iOS Device". I am able to import it into my app successfully. I just cant seem to access the class within.

Comment: Try clearing out the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder should fix any minor complications. Remove the framework from the app (embed, link) Build the framework again and try adding it again.
Also check if the target iOS version is same for both app and framework